# Google Cloud Secret Manager - Notifications on PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to configure Google Secret Manager in order to get notifications on PubSub (following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/event-notifications#create_a_secret_with_topics_configured)).

Is it possible to configure notifications on service level and not only on secret level?

I want to receive notifications on every secret of the project, without the need to explicitly to link a secret to the topic.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to configure a secret update notification at service level. Only the secret level is allowed.

However, in that case, I recommend to script the creation, or to use IaC solution, such as terraform, to automate the creation and the addition of the new secret notification to the existing topic.

To prevent manual creation, you can also remove the role to the users to force them to use your automated creation procedure.

Answer (score 0):

We can setup a notifications without creating a secret with particular topics.
We can make use of audit logs by creating a logs routing sink.
console.cloud.google.com/logs/router/, create a log routing sink with sink name, description and destination - (where your destination will be "cloud pub/sub topic"). In this way, notifications will be received upon any secret updates.